# Special characters when printing Word doc from Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I have a code in my application to print some data in word.
Somewhere in the code I do this:

```
gerarSumarioSeger = gerarSumarioSeger + |<p>| + docP.ds_assunto(0) + |</p>|
```

I assemble the HTML getting the data from the field in the document. Ok, not hard at all.
But, if I try to print two of the documents that have in this field the data like in the image

1. the word is generated with the error in image
2. [image]

   [image]

If I remove one of the "çã" in one of the fields the error doesn't occur.

If I put a hidden field with a special character like below the error doesn't occur:

```
<p style="visibility:hidden;">ã</p>
```

If I select another document with the content in the field like bellow the error doesn't occur:

> Convênio de Cooperação Geral - Sebrae e Ministério do Desenvolvimento
> Social e Agrário - MDSA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the character set to your html, something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: It was the charset, but not "UTF-8", worked with "windows-1258"